# VS2008 : Start an external program on Debug

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I have a solution with three projects:

1. is a console (GUI app) for a device connected through Serial Port.
2. Serial Port emulation (console app, self-hosted WCF service).
3. Common interfaces.

To debug, I start SerialPortEmulator and then debug (F5) the main project.

Two problems:

1. It takes extra keystrokes to start the emulator.
2. I need to remember to stop the emulator before compiling (in case there are breaking changes).

**Question**: Ideally I want to have emulator project be started on debug, and terminated on debug-stop. Is there easy way to do that?

I could have the emulator in a different solution, but then I need to ensure the interfaces definition library is always in sync.

Comment: there is no such thing as VS2009

Answer (score 1):

You can try to write a macro to catch the [`OnEnterRunMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291620(VS.71).aspx)

```
Private Sub DebuggerEvents_OnEnterRunMode(ByVal Reason As EnvDTE.dbgEventReason) _
    Handles DebuggerEvents.OnEnterRunMode

    // Run emulator here
End Sub
```

As for the clean of stop, have a look at my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033441/visual-studio-executing-clean-up-code-when-debugging-stops/1033518#1033518) (Executing clean up code when debugging stops)